# Am getting my "t" as undefined in the console and i do not know what is wrong with my code. How can I define my 't' in this code

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I was working a coding challenge in the course (tutorial on javascript)  and this was my alternative but i failed to figure it out so please help me.

```
// alternatine
const bill = [22, 295, 176, 440, 37, 105, 10, 1100, 86, 52];
const tipstxt = [];
const totalstxt = [];
// const tiptxt = cash
// const tip = (tiptxt);
for (let x = 0; x < bill.length; x++) {
  if (bill[x] >= 50 && bill[x] <= 300) t = 0.15 * bill[x];
  if (bill[x] <= 50 && bill[x] >= 300) t = 0.2 * bill[x];

  tipstxt.push(t);
}
console.log(tipstxt);
```

I expected if a value is between 50 to 300, then t=0.15*bill[x] and if not t=0.2*bill[x]

Comment: You need to define `t` with a `let t;` inside the for. Also, your second `if` is most probably wrong - a number can't be less than 50 AND more than 300! Probably you wanted to use `||` - or even better, else, and even better than that, the ternary operator `let t = (bill[x] >= 50 && bill[x] <= 300) ? 0.15 * bill[x] : 0.2 * bill[x];`

Comment: This means neither of your `if` statements matched and `t` was never defined.

Comment: Your second `if` condition is trying to be the opposite of the first, but fails to do so. If you have two opposite conditions, use a simple `if..else` instead.

Comment: "Creating a variable in JavaScript is called "declaring" a variable." https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: In most... well, many cases, it returns 'undefined' if you call an undeclaried variable. One of the many weird parts of JavaScript, is that not 'all' cases return 'undefined' when an undeclaried variable is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Your, second if statement will always evaluate to false because the expressions in your second if condition are contradictory.

`if (bill[x] <= 50 && bill[x] >= 300)`

bill[x] <= 50 will be true if bill[x] is less than or equal to 50, while

bill[x] >= 300 will be true if bill[x] is greater than or equal to 300.

Since a number cannot be lesser than 50 and greater than 300 at the same time, this if condition always evaluates to false.
So, the value of t remains undefined in case your first if statement also evaluates to false. Hence, the error.

The correct implementation of the second if statement would be:

```
if (bill[x] <= 50 || bill[x] >= 300)
```

whereby t can will be calculated if bill[x] is **either** *lesser than or equal to 50* **or** greater than or equal to 100.